# What does this signal mean ' in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

In this code snippet

```
return new this(`${last}, ${first} ${middle}`.trim(),
            utils.age(birthday),
            gender
        );
```

what does this signal mean ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the backtick symbol (`), it denotes a `template literal` or `template string`.

From the [Typescript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}). The expressions in the placeholders and the text between the backticks (` `) get passed to a function.

> The default function just concatenates the parts into a single string. If there is an expression preceding the template literal (tag here), this is called a tagged template. In that case, the tag expression (usually a function) gets called with the template literal, which you can then manipulate before outputting.